How to migrate Ember web application to Angular module by module
We have one web application developed in Ember js and we want to migrate it to latest Angular, but we want to migrate it module by module. so we need to coexist Angular and Ember both. and build should contain component from both libraries

Out of interest why are you migrating from Ember to Angular?

You'd probably have to customize routing in both applications and then migrate per route.
or mount whole angular apps as "islands" within the ember app, so you could migrate by-component -- rendering a new app/island per component within the ember app.
